# How do I use a nonstandard file descriptor for reading a file into an array with mapfile?

Tags: bash, file-descriptors, read, shell-builtin

`mapfile -t -u 7 arr < textfile` gives me
`bash: mapfile: 7: invalid file descriptor: Bad file descriptor`
Other, more verbose, methods of reading files line-by-line do allow for such descriptor, e.g.

```
read_w_while() {
while IFS="" read -u 7 -r l || [[ -n "${l}" ]]; do
  echo "${l}"
done 7< textfile
```

The standard descriptor, `0`, is used quite a lot.
Does using such descriptor make scripting more secure from interference? My experience is that so far I only witnessed, I am a Ubuntu Desktop user, such interference when using `while IFS="" read -u 7 ...` with the descriptor `7`. What might be the reasons of such interference.

Comment: I'm confused by what you want to *achieve* with `mapfile -t -u 7 arr < textfile`: this is self-contradictionary. On one hand, you clearly want to read `textfile` into `arr` by opening it and passing it as `stdin` file descriptor, as stated by `< textfile`, on the other hand, you clearly want to ignore `stdin` as input and instead read from file descriptor `7`, as stated by `-u 7`.

Comment: "so far I only witnessed ... such interference when using `while IFS="" read -u 7 ...`" -- umh, can you elaborate on that? Exactly what sort of interference have you witnessed? I'm not even exactly sure if you mean active (malicious) interference, or e.g. software bugs or such.

Comment: @ilkkachu `trimmer_conc_after() {
  of=$(echo "${if}"|sed -E "s/(\.)([abBevVimpoO4kw]{3,4}$)/\1trimmed\.$p_no.\2/")
  ffmpeg -loglevel warning -hide_banner -ss ${l} -i "${if}" -c copy "${of}" &&
  echo "${of}">>list_of_fragments
}` This function is the culprit. On second thought it must be `sed` that is inserting sometimes(in about 10-30% of executing this function) many lines of textual input that seemingly has nothing to do with the names of files. The issue seems to be unrelated to `read -r -u 7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `mapfile -t -u 7 arr < textfile` gives me.
> `bash: mapfile: 7: invalid file descriptor: Bad file descriptor`

Yes, it would, if fd 7 isn't open. `-u 7` *only* tells it to read from fd 7, it says nothing about how or where that fd should come to be.

In your second snippet, there's an input redirection `7< textfile` that opens a file on fd 7, so it should be quite natural that there, reading from fd 7 works.

You'd usually use another file descriptor for `read` if you have a need to use the original stdin at the same time, e.g. if you read from a file with a `while read ...` loop but also run something that reads from the terminal (stdin) within the loop.

Now, strictly speaking, the `-u fd` option is unnecessary, since the equivalent could be achieved with e.g. `read ... 0<&7`, but that has the downside that the shell needs to do some juggling to arrange the file descriptors in the correct places:

- first, duplicate fd 0 to some other number for safekeeping, say fd 9
- duplicate fd 7 to fd 0 (closing the old fd 0)
- run `read`, which reads from fd 0
- duplicate the original fd 0 from fd 9 (closing the current fd 0)
- close the now unnecessary copy in fd 9

All that, instead of just

- run `read -u 7`, which reads from fd 7

<sub>(I originally wrote "close fd 0" as an explicit step, but `dup2()` does close the destination fd automatically)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. *Yes, it would, if fd 7 isn't open. -u 7 only tells it to read from fd 7, it says nothing about how or where that fd should come to be.*                                                          `exec 7<textfile` before proceeding with `mapfile` solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in comments, `-u 7` and `< textfile` do not match.  You need to either omit `-u 7` or you need to change the redirection to `7< textfile` as in your second example to make this work.  The error is because file descriptor 7 is not open (yet).

As to security issues, I don't see how using file descriptor 7 will change security in any way.  The only reason to use another file descriptor like this would be if you want to preserve the pre-existing stdin for some other use within that pipeline.  And as this is a single command (mapfile) rather than a complex pipeline, this is moot.